# Spring Cloud Sleuth: Export data from remote system to local Zipkin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

In my Spring Boot application I use spring-cloud-starter-sleuth (Version Hoxton.SR10) for tracing. It is (still) a monolithic application so I widely use the `@NewSpan` annotation for creating new spans.

In my development environment I also use spring-cloud-starter-zipkin, which works great.

But on the servers of our customers I don't have access to any Zipkin server nor am allowed to install one. Is there any possibility to save the data Spring is sending to Zipkin and import that to my local Zipkin server?

---

**Solution thanks to Marcin's inspiration:**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "custom.property", havingValue = "true")
public class SleuthConfiguration {
    @Bean("zipkinSender")
    Sender restTemplateSender() {
        return new Sender() {
           public Encoding encoding() { return Encoding.JSON; }
           public int messageMaxBytes() { return Integer.MAX_VALUE; }
           public int messageSizeInBytes(List<byte[]> list) { return Integer.MAX_VALUE; }

           @Override
           public Call<Void> sendSpans(List<byte[]> list) {
              String result = convertByteArrayToList(list);
              saveToFile(result);
              return new Call.Base<Void>() {...};
           }
        };
     }
}
```

Implement `convertByteArrayToList` and `saveToFile` your own, because my solution depends on custom libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own `SpanHandler` bean that takes the `FinishedSpan`, converts into JSON and stores it somewhere on your drive. Then you could just iterate over jsons and upload them to the Zipkin server

Comment: Thank you @marcin-grzejszczak, I will implement it just like this! Producing custom SpanHandler and writing complete content (span.toString()) to a file called "span.traceId_span.id.json". As far as I understood joining the files still needs to be done manually. But that's ok :)

Comment: I don't think you need to join the files. Just send them to Zipkin and ZIpkin will join them

Comment: Hello Marcin, writing a file in in CustomSpanHandler.end turned out to be synchronous and influences the performance. I decided to hook into the sendSpans Method of "zipkinSender" Bean. That happens after request is completed so it's saver and not performance relevant.

Comment: You can write it in an asynchronous fashion. Nonetheless it's good that you found a solution that suits you!